# Appending tomcat logs to catalina.log stops, once user edits the log file

Tags: log4j2, slf4j, tomcat9, slf4j-api

Tomcat 9 was appending it's logs to catalina.log fine.
Since catalina.log contained too many content, for debugging my application, I wanted only fresh logs.

So I deleted all lines from log file and saved it. But soon after that, tomcat stopped writing logs to catalina.log until I restart my tomcat server again.

Once restarted, it again works fine and same happens if I delete lines again. I'm using slf4j configured to use log4j2 implementation. It's a Spring Boot application. Log4j2 is configured using xml file. xml file is same as xml file in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259405/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger-in-local-server-but-same-application-work/52370034#52370034) thread's answer.

How to delete log content without interrupting tomcat?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try running the following command:

```
$ echo > catalina.out
```

Comment: Even catalina.out behaves as same as other logs. echo > catalina.out gave nothing.

Comment: This is my typo: `echo > catalina.out` -> `echo > catalina.log`. Did you cd to $CATALINA_BASE/logs before running the command?

Comment: Yes I cd'd to $CATALINA_BASE/logs. But still that command is creating an empty catalina.log file. What it was supposed to do?